# Distributed Locking service in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, distributed, locks

We have a couple of Microservices deployed using EKS in AWS.

For these various services or multiple instances of these services, we need to implement a distributed lock.

What are the best options to implement this, using AWS services?

Comment: If a Java library can be used, see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/). Other discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/eer1er/atomic_locks_on_aws/).